# OS X 10.9.3 Update causing coreservicesd lag

Tags: finder

I'm getting a lot of stalling and high CPU usage when I open folders in Finder for the first time after the 10.9.3 update. Opening that folder again works fine, but expanding a folder of 20-30 files or folders stalls the CPU on these processes for 30 seconds:

> coreservicesd
>    com.apple.IconServicesAgent

I've tried relaunching Finder but the issue still occurs.

Comment: can you provide Console report at the time stamp

Comment: @Buscar웃 looking at it now, it seems the console isn't logging anything during these moments. I suspect this might in fact be caused by CleanMyMac 2 clearing local file caches in each directory something, but you'd think spotlight would resolve those.

Comment: The same issue here. Did a full recovery using Diskutil (which found quite some issues), but still happening.

Comment: I am having the same problem and I am NOT using CleanmyMac.
Also seeing same symptons running a script over multiple images in PshopCC.
and BridgeCC

Comment: @SteveS there's an accepted answer on this question -- did you try what it suggests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what fixed the problem for me:

- Rebuild the Quicklook cache (in Terminal: `qlmanage -r && qlmanage -r cache`)
- Rebuild Spotlight index (`sudo mdutil -E /`)

I'm not exactly sure which one of those two really caused the problem. You can try them separately.
It takes a while to rebuild both the cache/index, but afterwards Finder worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks for those. They executed fine but I still got the issue.

Comment: Sorry, false alarm my spotlight is building slowly :)

Comment: Neither rebuilding the Quicklook cache nor rebuilding the Spotlight index solved the problem for me - folders still take a long time to open, and coreservicesd and com.apple.IconServicesAgent still take up all the CPU.

Comment: @AlfEaton I had to wait for a few hours. After a few minutes the spotlight progress showed.